# Sum elements present in one column of a dataframe -> create a new column in the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of this type (2 rows,2 columns):

```
ID  Molecules  
1   AA, BB, CC  
2   FF, DD
```

I'd like to produce in R a new column corresponding to the number of molecules present in the "Molecules" column:

```
ID  Molecules    Number  
1   AA, BB, CC   3  
2   FF, DD       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of ways -

1. Count number of commas in the data and add 1 to it.

```
df$Number <- stringr::str_count(df$Molecules, ',') + 1
df

#  ID  Molecules Number
#1  1 AA, BB, CC      3
#2  2     FF, DD      2
```

2. split the data on comma and count the length.

```
df$Number <- lengths(strsplit(df$Molecules, ','))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Molecules = c("AA, BB, CC", "FF, DD"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```